# jq-update a value of a json adding a prefix

Tags: json, edit, jq

i've a json file like this

```
[{"id": 25422},{"id": 25423}]
```

and i like to update the id value and obtain this result

```
[{"id": "coupon25422"},{"id": "coupon25423"}]
```

Is this possible? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is.

```
$ jq -c 'map(.id |= "coupon\(.)")' <<< '[{"id": 25422},{"id": 25423}]'
[{"id":"coupon25422"},{"id":"coupon25423"}]
```

Comment: thank you, i tried to save the output to a file doing something like this `./jq -c 'map(.id |= "couponTippest_\(.)")' < coupon.json > coupon.json` but i get an empty file. what am i mistaking ?

Comment: @heartlex Use a temporary file, like: `jq -c 'map(.id |= "couponTippest_\(.)")' coupon.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json coupon.json`